# Scrollbars are not showing up in Spark DataGrid with Flex 4.5.1 but do show up with 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6

I have a Spark DataGrid that does not show Scrollbars when the SDK is 4.5 or earlier. If I set the SDK to 4.6 they show up correctly.

Has anyone seen this or knows how to get the scrollbars to show up correctly?

This is the CSS I used:

```
s|Scroll {
    skinClass: ClassReference("view.skins.CustomScrollerSkin");
}
```

This is the skin basically:

```
<!---  A horizontal scrollbar that lets you control the portion of data that is displayed 
when there is too much data to fit horizontally in a display area.
The Scroller determines whether the horizontal ScrollBar is visible. -->
<fx:Component  id="horizontalScrollBarFactory">
    <s:HScrollBar visible="false" />
</fx:Component>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Wouldn't have noticed that without you.

Comment: Sigh... Updated question

Comment: You'll have to provide more context. It normally doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The behavior of Flex 4.6 is different than 4.5.

In Flex 4.5.1 this skin above would hide the scroller because those skin parts had visible=false. In Flex 4.6 this would **not** hide the scroller. I removed the skin / selector from that component.

This cause of this is I believe has to do with the newer on demand scroller SDK introduced in 4.6.

> Several under-the-hood enhancements have been made to Scroller. First
>   and foremost, scroll bars are now created on demand. This means your
>   application does not spend time up-front creating scrollbars for
>   content until the content is scrolled, resulting in a view creation
>   performance boost. [1]

[1] http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/introducing-flex46sdk.html